# Set master file in vim-latex (TeX-Suite)

Tags: compiling, vim, vim-latex

When I type `<leader>ll` in Vim with [`vim-latex`](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/index.php) installed, I can compile the .tex file in my current buffer.

But the .tex file I'm editing is actually just `\input{}`ed into a master .tex file.

How can I tell `vim-latex` to always compile my master document?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are instructions on how to do this [here](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite/latex-project.html).

For master file called `my_master.tex`, create a file in either the same directory as your `\input{}`ed file or a directory anywhere above that one called:

```
my_master.tex.latexmain
```

Now typing `<leader>ll` will compile the master document of whichever .tex file you currently have on screen.